# html header meta refresh doesn't work for the first time in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a page using noscript code when there is no javascript enable it has to redirect to error page

```
<noscript> 
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/error.html" />
</noscript>
```

but here i am facing two problems

1. when i am disable javascript and trying to reload the page on chrome for the first time when I refresh page, the page is not getting redirected to the error page. When I refresh the page again for the second time, it is getting redirecting to error page.
2. When i enable javascript in settings and try to refresh the page, for the first time it is displaying error page itself and when I refresh again page it is redirecting to my index page

Comment: Can you show us the reset of the page code?

Comment: <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>SAMPLE</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sample.css" />

        <div id="example1">
        <div id="example2">
        <div class="javascriptDisabled"> 
            Javascript disabled
  </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: What's the behavior on other browsers?

Comment: it is working fine on firefox and IE. Page is redirecting to error page for the first itself

Comment: @anonymous232 where the 'meta' tag is placed?

Comment: in the header of index.html(main page) file

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232410) that only happens right after you disable JavaScript. Users browsing with JavaScript disabled all the time (God help them) will not have this issue.